# Unable to View Newly Inserted Data in Navicat After Setting MySQL Configuration autocommit to 0

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have set autocommit to 0 in the MySQL configuration file and added @Transactional annotation to the Service method in Spring Boot to ensure transaction integrity. However, when I try to view the data using database management tools like Navicat, I find that I cannot see the newly inserted data. I suspect that this might be due to the transaction not being committed.

I have tried checking the transaction status of the database and manually committing the transaction, but the issue persists. I would like to know why I am unable to see the newly inserted data in the database management tool in this scenario. Has anyone encountered a similar situation or knows the possible reasons and solutions? Thanks for your help!

Based on my understanding, I expected that using @Transactional would leverage Spring's transaction management, and Spring would commit the transaction automatically. However, it seems that this is not the case. When I changed the MySQL autocommit to 1, I was able to see the newly inserted data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.